# Term for the initial developer of a start-up?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Imagine that you have developed a software from scratch for a start-up. You are not a co-founder, but you are the person who has created the source code repository, and has written pretty much all of the code.

What would be the term for such position to put in a résumé? *Chief Technical Officer* sounds like it is more of a management position, rather than actually being involved in building the software.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Just like *silverware* and *tableware*, *stoneware* and *spyware*, the word *software* functions only as a mass noun in English, not as a count noun that you get to use the **indefinite article *a*** before. If you want something countable, then you can call it *a program* or *a **piece of** software*. You might be interested in our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the information, but linking to ELL was a bit harsh :)

Comment: You were the main or chief developer (or programmer) of the software for a startup in the field of ___ (if you don't want to name the company).

Comment: @Xanne **Primary** or **lead** developer would also be acceptable terms. From the OP's description, however I think **main** or **primary** could be the best options as **chief** and **lead** imply heading up a team and it sounds as though the development was essentially a solo effort.

Comment: @BoldBen Good point.  I like "software architect" or "main software architect" also as possibilities.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, the "architect" terms are good but their suitability would depend on the involvement of the developer in the original concept. If the startup CEO had the original idea but needed to employ the OP for his technical skills the term "architect" doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree--CEO may have at least part of the "architect" role; but OP is clear about the role I'd call engineering--developing the software "from scratch" and creating the source code repository (and maintaining it, perhaps?).

Comment: Is your question about the *initial* developer (*per* question title) or the one who did the *most* coding (*per* question body)?

Comment: @Xanne, I think we're on the same page here!

Answer (score 1):

Software Architect.

Guru works but not for a resume. Often Engineers will operate under the title of President, or CEO. My boss goes by President, and Sr. Engineer. The President of a software company knows about code.

I once worked for a company who's CTO was a programmer yes yes yes. Often the CTO is more of a DBA/System Administrator type it seems.

I really enjoyed this question, My name is Jesse Ivy, I am an author, and when I got my first job out of college I was hired as Software Engineer, shortly after I realized there was not any promotion I could receive. :)

Currently I am working under the title of Developer, writing a Java/MySQL API which administers an important curriculum. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

"Senior Developer" is a common term for this. Many companies distinguish between their stock of developers and those that lead development activities — the "senior developers" or "lead developers".